# Python HTTP server with XML-RPC

Tags: python, http, xml-rpc

I have a server that has to respond to HTTP and XML-RPC requests. Right now I have an instance of SimpleXMLRPCServer, and an instance of BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer with a custom request handler, running on different ports. I'd like to run both services on a single port.

I think it should be possible to modify the CGIXMLRPCRequestHandler class to also serve custom HTTP requests on some paths, or alternately, to use multiple request handlers based on what path is requested. I'm not really sure what the cleanest way to do this would be, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SimpleXMLRPCDispatcher` class directly from your own request handler.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it'll work! For future reference, the _marshaled_dispatch method was the really useful one

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason not to run a real webserver out front with url rewrites to the two ports you are usign now? It's going to make life much easier in the long run

Comment: I'm writing a standalone desktop application, so requiring a standalone web server would definitely be too much work for the user to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be (tested for Python 3.3 but should work for 2.x with modified imports):

```
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler,SimpleXMLRPCServer

class MixRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler,SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    pass

srv=SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost",8080),MixRequestHandler)
#normal stuff for SimpleXMLRPCServer
```